# To return the multiple values from for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop, return-value

I have parsed the xml document and used a for loop to loop for getting different values in string, but when I try to return the value I get only the last value obtained, I want to return all the individual values so that I can store that values in any file format,
Below is my code,

```
XmlDocument xmlDOC = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDOC.LoadXml(periodID_Value_Before_OffSet); // string storing my XML 
       var value = xmlDOC.GetElementsByTagName("value");
       var xmlActions = new string[value.Count];
       string values = "";
       string Period1 = "";
       string periodlevel_period1 = "";
       var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
       string modified_listofstrings = listOfStrings.ToString();
       string arrayOfStrings = ""; 
       for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
       {
           var xmlAttributeCollection = value[i].Attributes;
           if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
           {
               var action = xmlAttributeCollection["periodid"];
               xmlActions[i] = action.Value;
               values += action.Value + ",";
               string vals = values.Split(',')[1];
               string counts = values;
               string[] periods = counts.Split(',');
               Period1 = periods[i];
               // periodlevel_period1 = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, Period1, "name", "");
                  modified_listofstrings = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, Period1, "name", "");
                  modified_listofstrings.ToArray().ToString();
                  //listOfStrings = periodlevel_period1;
               }
           }
    return modified_listofstrings;
```

This modified_listofstrings string only return last on value, I want to return the array of the values all obtained while looping.

----------Updated question----------
below is my Sample XMl

```
   <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <ResultSetHierarchy totalResultsReturned="1" totalResults="1" firstIndex="0" maxCount="-1"> 
   <object id="SC.1938773693.238"> 
     <measure.values> 
       <series id="SC.1938773693.108280985"> 
       <value periodid="SC.1938773693.394400760" value="17" /> 
       <value periodid="SC.1938773693.1282504058" value="15" /> 
       <value periodid="SC.1938773693.1631528570" value="13" />
       </series>
       </object> 
   </ResultSetHierarchy>
 </string>
```

I want output as **"SC.1938773693.394400760":"17"** and so on for all periodid

Comment: It's very hard to tell how you are trying to build the list since you aren't really even using List.  But as regards your variable, you need += to make it grow:  modified_listofstrings += QPR_webService_Client.....  You only have =.

Comment: user1646737.. when I am coding as explained by you, i get the output as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]Q1 / 2013Q2 / 2013Q3 / 2013Q1 / 2013Q2 / 2013Q3 / 2013Q1 / 2013Q2 / 2013Q3 / 2013...I just want values in different string variables since I need to plot them for eg string a = Q1 / 2013, string b= Q2 / 2013 and so on, I want to return array of string values in short if I am not wrong, is that possible...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the provided information I have updated the answer.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
XmlDocument xmlDOC = new XmlDocument();
xmlDOC.Load(@"E:\Delete Me\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\List.xml");
var elements = xmlDOC.GetElementsByTagName("value");

foreach (var item in elements)
{
   XmlElement value = (XmlElement)item;
   items.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", value.GetAttribute("periodid"), value.GetAttribute("value")));
}
```

Comment: while returning modified_listofstrings, I am getting error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.List<strings>' to 'string'

Comment: @Reshma change return type of your function from `string` to `List<string>`

Comment: Assuming that each call of QPR_webService_Client took noticeable delay, it would be even better if you store the result as IEnumerable<strings> using yield return, that way the consuming process could use the first result right away instead of waiting for all the result

Comment: @Vimal CK..Since I pass periodid in xmlAttributeCollection i get only periodid, but i also wants its corresponding value against it so that I want the output as Q1 / 2013: 12 somewhat as key value structure, plz can you suggest for some mechanism

Comment: @Reshma Could you please share me the xml sample and the output you want. Sometimes I could suggest a good way to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to:

1. Load an XmlDocument
2. Get a list of all the attributes of name 'periodid'
3. Look each periodid up using a webservice call
4. Return a list of the lookup results

If that is correct, the following method should do what you need:

```
    public List<string> GetListOfData()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDOC = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDOC.LoadXml("<Html><value periodid='Yabba'>YabbaValue</value><value periodid='Dabba'>DabbaValue</value><value periodid='Doo'>DooValue</value></Html>"); // string storing my XML 

        var value = xmlDOC.GetElementsByTagName("value");

        var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            var xmlAttributeCollection = value[i].Attributes;

            if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
            {
                var action = xmlAttributeCollection["periodid"];
                string Period1 = action.Value;
                listOfStrings.Add(QPR_webService_Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, Period1, "name", "") + ":" + value[i].InnerText);
            }
        }
        return listOfStrings;
    }
```

Comment: Baldrick.. I get period Id but cant I get something like period id in one variable and it's corresponding value in any other variable as in the format of key value format coz my main aim is to write the value in txt file in JSON format as "periodid":"It's value"...any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the post. It now returns a list of strings, each of which is PeriodID:Value.

Comment: no no... I get the period id as Q1 / 2013 and its value as 12 so my output must be Q1 / 2013 : 12...I hope you get me

Comment: I think the code above should do that. What is the output of the above code for you?

Comment: <string>Q1 / 2013</string>
<string>Q2 / 2013</string>
<string>Q3 / 2013</string>
<string>Q1 / 2013</string>
<string>Q2 / 2013</string>
<string>Q3 / 2013</string>
<string>Q1 / 2013</string>
<string>Q2 / 2013</string>
<string>Q3 / 2013</string>... the above code gives me this if I return the value to check and if I replace the periodid with value

Comment: then I get <string>17</string>
<string>15</string>
<string>13</string>
<string>14.103</string>
<string>14.404499999999999</string>
<string>14.966999999999999</string>
<string>15.67</string>
<string>16.005</string>
<string>16.63</string> as output.. I want period id and its value against each other so it will be easy for me to consider which value belongs to which perioid

Comment: I'm not sure you have my latest code from above. Every string is build from Period1 + ":" + QPR_webService_Client_ call. You should at least have a : in your output...

Comment: <string>SC.1938773693.394400760:Q1 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.1282504058:Q2 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.1631528570:Q3 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.394400760:Q1 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.1282504058:Q2 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.1631528570:Q3 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.394400760:Q1 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.1282504058:Q2 / 2013</string>
<string>SC.1938773693.1631528570:Q3 / 2013</string>...this is the output I am getting when I write as said you above, it is when I put  periodid,

Comment: but when I write value I get values for this period... I want both name of the periodid that is Q3/2013 and its value against it, I don't want its id that is SC.1938773693.1631528570..I hope you understand it

Comment: For eg..in code explained by you,  yabba is periodid and its value is yabbavalue.. i want yabba:yabbavalue

Comment: Ok - I follow you. I've updated my post. See if that works for you.

Comment: I debugged it and it seems that because of periodid in xmlAttributeCollection..it gives only periodid and not its value..so final output is shown like Q1/2013:..thats it..no value

Comment: I think I've done as much as I can with the code - and you can see how it works in the debugger. I think it's up to you now - use the watch window to play around and find out which data you want to see on the right hand side of the : . Best of luck.

Comment: .k...Thanks a lot for help till now,hv a nice day.